# How to remove overlap when using ffmpeg concat?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concat two files, but the second file repeats the final two seconds of the first, creating a tiny, irritating loop in the middle. Here's my script, based on [this documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy final.avi
```

mylist.txt:

```
file '[Part1].avi'
file '[Part2].avi' inpoint 2
```

`inpoint` doesn't seem to be doing anything when used this way—I can set it to anything and it won't make a difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: do you fix this?

Comment: @VnDevil, it was a long time ago, but I believe the accepted answer fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut the first 2 seconds of the second video:

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i '[Part2].avi' -strict -2 -qscale 0 Part2-trimmed.avi
```

Then concatenate the first video and the new one:

```
ffmpeg -i '[Part1].avi' -i Part2-trimmed.avi -lavfi "concat=n=2:v=1" -strict -2 -qscale 0 final.avi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put each command on a separate line when using ffmpeg's concat demuxer:

```
file '[Part1].avi'
file '[Part2].avi'
inpoint 2
```

Because you put `inpoint` on the same line as `file`, it was ignored.

Each directive such as `inpoint` applies to the most recent `file` line above it.  All available directives are listed [in the documentation for the concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).