# Lossless concat overlapping videos (mp4) smoothly using ffmpeg & python?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, python

I have a list of videos some of which overlap which I want to concatenate continuously and losslessly. What I mean by continuously is that the videos are stitched together with overlapping part being omitted. For example, let say we have the following list `vidlist.txt`:

```
video1.mp4   (25 seconds long)
video2.mp4   (15 seconds long)
```

and the last 10 seconds of `video1.mp4` is identical (overlaps) with the first 10 seconds of `video2.mp4`. So concatenated video `output.mp4` should be only 30 seconds long with no repeating/duplicated/overlapped part: `0~25s of video1.mp4` + `10~15s of video2.mp4` OR `0~15s of video1.mp4` + `0~15s of video2.mp4`.

What I've tried so far:

1. I found [this QnA](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24681) which exactly does the job, except that it re-encodes (thus lossy). It seems to me that the code searches for the first identical frame and then marks the time of that first identical frame as `inpoint` for `concat`.
2. Then I found a command that simply joins two videos losslessly: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist.txt -c copy output.mp4` so I tried using that `inpoint` in #1 to split the second video (or first), then concatenate using this code. It does the job losslessly, but the stitching part has unnatural, unsynchronized video & audio.
3. I added `-segment_time_metadata 1` option so that `ffmpeg -f concat -segment_time_metadata 1 -safe 0 -i vidlist.txt -c copy output.mp4`, and this seems to resolve video desync, but audio remains unnatural.

PS. I'm only interested in video being lossless. Audio can be lossy/resampled.

Comment: Are they dashcam videos? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447495/no-accepted-answer-how-to-merge-2-overlapping-videos-into-one-video-using-ffmp

Comment: @Gantendo No. They are recordings by the same device, so they share same framerate, bitrate, codec, etc.

Comment: @Gantendo The answer in that QnA **re-encodes** the videos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove overlap when using ffmpeg concat?](https://superuser.com/questions/977209/how-to-remove-overlap-when-using-ffmpeg-concat)

Answer (score 0):

I set the video codec to simple `-c:v copy`, and audio filter to `-af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1`. Fully expressed,

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts+igndts -f concat -safe 0 -segment_time_metadata 1 -i vidlist.txt -c:v copy -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1 output.mp4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).